# how to add search box on specific page?

Tags: 7, search

I need to show the search box on that page and specific search if sometime type related news then search result appear. I need only the search box for this content type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to display the 'Search form' block for a specific content type.

On `admin/structure/block/manage/search/form/configure` you can change the 'Visibility settings' and show the block for specific content types. Below a screenshot where I have selected to display the search form on nodes of my custom content type 'Blog overview':

[image: Block visibility settings for specific content types]

Comment: search form block is working fine and i need another search form which is working for latest news only